# Convert data frame to spatial lines data frame in R with x,y x,y coordintates

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial-data-frame

I have a data frame in R, one of the columns contains the coordinates for points along a line in the form:

```
x,y x,y x,y x,y
```

So the whole data frame looks like

```
id dist speed coord
1  45   6     1.294832,54.610240 -1.294883,54.610080 -1.294262,54.6482757
2  23   34    2.788732,34.787940 6.294883,24.567080 -5.564262,-45.7676757
```

I would like to convert this to a spatial lines data frame, and I assume that the fist step would be to separate the coordinates into two columns in the from:

```
x, x, x, x
y, y, y, y
```

But I am unsure how to proceed.

EDIT

For those requesting it a dput of the actual file

```
> finalsub <- final[final$rid <3,]
> dput(finalsub)
structure(list(rid = c(1, 2), start_id = c(1L, 1L), start_code = c("E02002536", 
"E02002536"), end_id = c(106L, 106L), end_code = c("E02006909", 
"E02006909"), strategy = c("fastest", "quietest"), distance = c(12655L, 
12909L), time_seconds = c(2921L, 3422L), calories = c(211L, 201L
), document.id = c(1L, 1L), array.index = 1:2, start = c("Geranium Close", 
"Geranium Close"), finish = c("Hylton Road", "Hylton Road"), 
    startBearing = c(0, 0), startSpeed = c(0, 0), start_longitude = c(-1.294832, 
    -1.294832), start_latitude = c(54.610241, 54.610241), finish_longitude = c(-1.249478, 
    -1.249478), finish_latitude = c(54.680691, 54.680691), crow_fly_distance = c(8362, 
    8362), event = c("depart", "depart"), whence = c(1473171787, 
    1473171787), speed = c(20, 20), itinerary = c(419956, 419957
    ), clientRouteId = c(0, 0), plan = c("fastest", "quietest"
    ), note = c("", ""), length = c(12655, 12909), time = c(2921, 
    3422), busynance = c(42172, 17242), quietness = c(30, 75), 
    signalledJunctions = c(3, 4), signalledCrossings = c(2, 0
    ), west = c(-1.300074, -1.294883), south = c(54.610006, 54.609851
    ), east = c(-1.232447, -1.232447), north = c(54.683814, 54.683814
    ), name = c("Geranium Close to Hylton Road", "Geranium Close to Hylton Road"
    ), walk = c(0, 0), leaving = c("2016-09-06 15:23:07", "2016-09-06 15:23:07"
    ), arriving = c("2016-09-06 16:11:48", "2016-09-06 16:20:09"
    ), coordinates = c("-1.294832,54.610240 -1.294883,54.610080 -1.294262,54.610016 -1.294141,54.610006 -1.293710,54.610038 -1.293726,54.610142 -1.293742,54.610247 -1.293510,54.610262 -1.293368,54.610258 -1.292816,54.610195 -1.292489,54.610152 -1.292298,54.610667 -1.292205,54.610951 -1.292182,54.611063 -1.292183,54.611153 -1.292239,54.611341 -1.292305,54.611447 -1.292375,54.611534 -1.292494,54.611639 -1.292739,54.611830 -1.292909,54.611980 -1.293010,54.612107 -1.293111,54.612262 -1.293192,54.612423 -1.293235,54.612546 -1.293267,54.612684 -1.293279,54.612818 -1.293510,54.612813 -1.293732,54.612790 -1.294324,54.612691 -1.295086,54.612568 -1.295313,54.612539 -1.295379,54.612543 -1.295889,54.612645 -1.295945,54.612648 -1.296006,54.612642 -1.297154,54.612414 -1.297502,54.612895 -1.297733,54.612847 -1.297990,54.612796 -1.298292,54.612747 -1.298515,54.612727 -1.299088,54.612681 -1.299564,54.612669 -1.299798,54.612663 -1.300006,54.612660 -1.300057,54.612809 -1.300056,54.613335 -1.300071,54.613693 -1.300074,54.614044 -1.300042,54.614482 -1.300015,54.614786 -1.299947,54.615220 -1.299907,54.615394 -1.299854,54.615644 -1.299730,54.616048 -1.299495,54.616700 -1.299196,54.617347 -1.298236,54.619313 -1.298010,54.619762 -1.297703,54.620418 -1.297520,54.620831 -1.297169,54.621690 -1.297061,54.621981 -1.296416,54.623873 -1.296310,54.624308 -1.296225,54.624888 -1.296215,54.625286 -1.296220,54.625546 -1.296241,54.625803 -1.296268,54.625913 -1.296323,54.626011 -1.296397,54.626096 -1.296540,54.626190 -1.296719,54.626323 -1.296893,54.626433 -1.297042,54.626589 -1.297111,54.626710 -1.297122,54.626825 -1.297110,54.626948 -1.297058,54.627052 -1.296961,54.627172 -1.296861,54.627258 -1.296760,54.627325 -1.296603,54.627397 -1.296491,54.627438 -1.296338,54.627472 -1.296154,54.627496 -1.295966,54.627513 -1.295746,54.627526 -1.295618,54.627522 -1.295421,54.627510 -1.295197,54.627466 -1.295102,54.627436 -1.294832,54.627376 -1.294665,54.627355 -1.294502,54.627350 -1.294331,54.627366 -1.294014,54.627415 -1.293557,54.627499 -1.293001,54.627611 -1.292613,54.627701 -1.291836,54.627902 -1.291248,54.628076 -1.290635,54.628269 -1.290142,54.628446 -1.289621,54.628649 -1.289031,54.628903 -1.288538,54.629137 -1.288132,54.629350 -1.287681,54.629604 -1.287262,54.629862 -1.286866,54.630124 -1.286103,54.630643 -1.285748,54.630868 -1.285396,54.631082 -1.284974,54.631322 -1.284541,54.631540 -1.284101,54.631752 -1.283390,54.632048 -1.282592,54.632385 -1.282161,54.632566 -1.281762,54.632734 -1.281111,54.633011 -1.280519,54.633274 -1.280009,54.633501 -1.279834,54.633579 -1.279392,54.633781 -1.278434,54.634210 -1.277896,54.634457 -1.276936,54.634898 -1.276210,54.635223 -1.275594,54.635485 -1.274596,54.635891 -1.273929,54.636180 -1.273392,54.636428 -1.272814,54.636726 -1.271627,54.637353 -1.271084,54.637605 -1.270550,54.637825 -1.269916,54.638054 -1.269389,54.638222 -1.268821,54.638383 -1.268165,54.638555 -1.265953,54.639131 -1.263766,54.639693 -1.262790,54.639953 -1.262005,54.640154 -1.261340,54.640329 -1.260658,54.640532 -1.260123,54.640712 -1.259489,54.640957 -1.258639,54.641312 -1.258010,54.641554 -1.257141,54.641861 -1.255996,54.642247 -1.254429,54.642787 -1.253524,54.643099 -1.252790,54.643343 -1.251636,54.643727 -1.250900,54.643982 -1.250258,54.644219 -1.249668,54.644419 -1.249123,54.644623 -1.248778,54.644762 -1.246709,54.645642 -1.244773,54.646492 -1.244140,54.646746 -1.243551,54.646973 -1.242738,54.647233 -1.242353,54.647360 -1.241810,54.647503 -1.241182,54.647642 -1.240373,54.647780 -1.239950,54.647854 -1.239961,54.647890 -1.239435,54.647967 -1.239583,54.649724 -1.239343,54.649878 -1.239011,54.650011 -1.237692,54.650177 -1.236610,54.650296 -1.236417,54.650323 -1.236257,54.650351 -1.236015,54.650414 -1.235833,54.650469 -1.235081,54.650723 -1.234846,54.650805 -1.234312,54.650977 -1.234094,54.651025 -1.233980,54.651044 -1.233308,54.651137 -1.233173,54.651160 -1.233063,54.651200 -1.232967,54.651252 -1.232849,54.651347 -1.232814,54.651423 -1.232810,54.651495 -1.232823,54.651569 -1.232840,54.651893 -1.232827,54.652010 -1.232504,54.653177 -1.232447,54.653500 -1.232451,54.653723 -1.232474,54.653943 -1.232535,54.654301 -1.232590,54.654635 -1.232903,54.654627 -1.232948,54.655599 -1.232982,54.656334 -1.232795,54.656365 -1.233131,54.658020 -1.233336,54.658428 -1.233507,54.658699 -1.233592,54.658803 -1.234197,54.659389 -1.234690,54.659825 -1.234979,54.660119 -1.235153,54.660314 -1.235343,54.660572 -1.235566,54.661037 -1.235656,54.661355 -1.235690,54.661638 -1.235677,54.661902 -1.235677,54.661984 -1.235683,54.663215 -1.235656,54.663632 -1.235639,54.664273 -1.235613,54.664639 -1.235593,54.664822 -1.235566,54.664957 -1.235508,54.665351 -1.235197,54.667327 -1.235120,54.668542 -1.235100,54.668897 -1.235199,54.669535 -1.235358,54.670231 -1.235437,54.670482 -1.235756,54.671241 -1.236144,54.672181 -1.236375,54.672971 -1.236309,54.673562 -1.236286,54.673704 -1.236127,54.674365 -1.235918,54.675272 -1.235827,54.675620 -1.235749,54.675960 -1.235735,54.676152 -1.235740,54.676328 -1.235754,54.676598 -1.235770,54.676987 -1.235771,54.677013 -1.235793,54.677480 -1.235758,54.677760 -1.235607,54.678134 -1.235470,54.678420 -1.235167,54.678875 -1.234263,54.679929 -1.234207,54.680065 -1.234175,54.680201 -1.234204,54.680465 -1.234300,54.681119 -1.234362,54.681549 -1.234427,54.681771 -1.234560,54.682172 -1.234782,54.682824 -1.236530,54.682837 -1.236725,54.682829 -1.237133,54.682813 -1.238813,54.683143 -1.241021,54.683814 -1.241819,54.683771 -1.242854,54.683717 -1.242946,54.683718 -1.243082,54.683716 -1.244694,54.683772 -1.244658,54.683077 -1.245038,54.682805 -1.245047,54.681990 -1.245011,54.681238 -1.245220,54.680975 -1.247056,54.680601 -1.248019,54.680404 -1.249478,54.680691", 
    "-1.294832,54.610240 -1.294883,54.610080 -1.294262,54.610016 -1.294141,54.610006 -1.293710,54.610038 -1.293726,54.610142 -1.293742,54.610247 -1.293510,54.610262 -1.293368,54.610258 -1.292816,54.610195 -1.292489,54.610152 -1.292298,54.610667 -1.292167,54.610651 -1.291371,54.610562 -1.291240,54.610556 -1.291107,54.610564 -1.290983,54.610581 -1.290467,54.610665 -1.290253,54.610690 -1.290017,54.610689 -1.289770,54.610665 -1.289500,54.610620 -1.289281,54.610570 -1.289124,54.610514 -1.288957,54.610440 -1.288611,54.610277 -1.288420,54.610222 -1.287445,54.610110 -1.287259,54.610664 -1.286758,54.610611 -1.285446,54.610462 -1.285308,54.610459 -1.283356,54.610475 -1.283159,54.610475 -1.283156,54.610324 -1.283153,54.610119 -1.282818,54.610118 -1.282560,54.610114 -1.282110,54.610131 -1.281962,54.610153 -1.281788,54.610200 -1.281639,54.610257 -1.281298,54.609964 -1.281196,54.609851 -1.280586,54.610008 -1.280272,54.610054 -1.279816,54.610091 -1.279480,54.610104 -1.279112,54.610121 -1.278953,54.610146 -1.278815,54.610183 -1.278669,54.610225 -1.278524,54.610279 -1.278428,54.610326 -1.278327,54.610377 -1.278042,54.610237 -1.277946,54.610211 -1.277849,54.610204 -1.277454,54.610206 -1.277268,54.610211 -1.276621,54.610222 -1.276217,54.610233 -1.276085,54.610240 -1.275571,54.610315 -1.275426,54.610347 -1.275334,54.610373 -1.275248,54.610417 -1.275204,54.610477 -1.275066,54.610765 -1.274836,54.611248 -1.274811,54.611349 -1.274833,54.611414 -1.274925,54.611607 -1.274953,54.611664 -1.274669,54.611698 -1.272541,54.610433 -1.271290,54.610716 -1.270069,54.611677 -1.269365,54.611847 -1.268450,54.612165 -1.267142,54.612923 -1.266539,54.613386 -1.265920,54.614177 -1.265663,54.614259 -1.264195,54.616131 -1.263730,54.616670 -1.263665,54.616739 -1.263407,54.617051 -1.262407,54.618192 -1.262185,54.618424 -1.262077,54.618537 -1.261506,54.619136 -1.261394,54.619342 -1.261507,54.619520 -1.261799,54.620013 -1.261791,54.620138 -1.261695,54.620233 -1.261342,54.620279 -1.261237,54.620334 -1.261175,54.620442 -1.261128,54.620493 -1.260857,54.620616 -1.260783,54.620697 -1.260729,54.620807 -1.260729,54.620942 -1.260677,54.621042 -1.260600,54.621109 -1.260457,54.621250 -1.260409,54.621298 -1.260364,54.621336 -1.260140,54.621409 -1.260052,54.621475 -1.259959,54.621607 -1.259881,54.621722 -1.259603,54.622326 -1.259445,54.622670 -1.259349,54.623096 -1.259359,54.623266 -1.259490,54.623825 -1.259497,54.623856 -1.259882,54.624563 -1.259894,54.624684 -1.259646,54.624993 -1.259529,54.625176 -1.259093,54.625999 -1.258939,54.626244 -1.258780,54.626429 -1.258157,54.626772 -1.257604,54.627106 -1.256140,54.627787 -1.255933,54.627903 -1.255874,54.627953 -1.255754,54.628092 -1.255576,54.628504 -1.255534,54.628645 -1.255601,54.629176 -1.255572,54.629415 -1.255265,54.630017 -1.255104,54.630209 -1.254200,54.630725 -1.254084,54.630831 -1.254037,54.630915 -1.254018,54.631129 -1.254128,54.631712 -1.254107,54.631961 -1.253979,54.632187 -1.253594,54.632613 -1.253530,54.632749 -1.253501,54.632882 -1.253404,54.633827 -1.253482,54.634447 -1.253483,54.634654 -1.253445,54.634902 -1.253389,54.635040 -1.253275,54.635186 -1.252555,54.635902 -1.252473,54.636063 -1.252330,54.636859 -1.252273,54.637015 -1.252176,54.637175 -1.251977,54.637365 -1.251763,54.637507 -1.251314,54.637755 -1.250800,54.638114 -1.250487,54.638358 -1.250153,54.638709 -1.249968,54.638840 -1.249562,54.639001 -1.248455,54.639365 -1.248124,54.639494 -1.247386,54.639821 -1.246797,54.640013 -1.246610,54.640098 -1.246513,54.640170 -1.246574,54.640279 -1.247014,54.640580 -1.247341,54.641088 -1.247564,54.641365 -1.248256,54.642661 -1.248319,54.642919 -1.247650,54.643048 -1.246829,54.643234 -1.245867,54.643306 -1.245202,54.643286 -1.243595,54.643087 -1.243282,54.643073 -1.242962,54.643076 -1.242041,54.643065 -1.241790,54.643031 -1.241369,54.642888 -1.240421,54.642544 -1.240237,54.642499 -1.240075,54.642497 -1.239926,54.642545 -1.239858,54.642627 -1.239837,54.642696 -1.239909,54.642989 -1.239960,54.643498 -1.239964,54.643532 -1.239983,54.644175 -1.239936,54.644470 -1.239883,54.644807 -1.239842,54.645116 -1.239825,54.645489 -1.239748,54.646014 -1.239733,54.646299 -1.239798,54.646734 -1.239789,54.646896 -1.239705,54.647229 -1.239683,54.647331 -1.239608,54.647496 -1.239566,54.647621 -1.239562,54.647760 -1.239618,54.647903 -1.239421,54.647932 -1.239435,54.647967 -1.239583,54.649724 -1.239343,54.649878 -1.239011,54.650011 -1.237692,54.650177 -1.236610,54.650296 -1.236417,54.650323 -1.236257,54.650351 -1.236015,54.650414 -1.235833,54.650469 -1.235081,54.650723 -1.234846,54.650805 -1.234312,54.650977 -1.234094,54.651025 -1.233980,54.651044 -1.233308,54.651137 -1.233173,54.651160 -1.233063,54.651200 -1.232967,54.651252 -1.232849,54.651347 -1.232814,54.651423 -1.232810,54.651495 -1.232823,54.651569 -1.232840,54.651893 -1.232827,54.652010 -1.232504,54.653177 -1.232447,54.653500 -1.232451,54.653723 -1.232474,54.653943 -1.232535,54.654301 -1.232590,54.654635 -1.232619,54.654960 -1.232723,54.655606 -1.232795,54.656365 -1.233131,54.658020 -1.233336,54.658428 -1.233507,54.658699 -1.233592,54.658803 -1.234197,54.659389 -1.234690,54.659825 -1.234979,54.660119 -1.235153,54.660314 -1.235343,54.660572 -1.235566,54.661037 -1.235656,54.661355 -1.235690,54.661638 -1.235677,54.661902 -1.235677,54.661984 -1.235683,54.663215 -1.235656,54.663632 -1.235639,54.664273 -1.235613,54.664639 -1.235593,54.664822 -1.235566,54.664957 -1.235508,54.665351 -1.235197,54.667327 -1.235120,54.668542 -1.235100,54.668897 -1.235199,54.669535 -1.235358,54.670231 -1.235437,54.670482 -1.235756,54.671241 -1.236144,54.672181 -1.236375,54.672971 -1.236309,54.673562 -1.236286,54.673704 -1.236127,54.674365 -1.235918,54.675272 -1.235827,54.675620 -1.235749,54.675960 -1.235735,54.676152 -1.235740,54.676328 -1.235754,54.676598 -1.235770,54.676987 -1.235771,54.677013 -1.235793,54.677480 -1.235758,54.677760 -1.235607,54.678134 -1.235470,54.678420 -1.235167,54.678875 -1.234263,54.679929 -1.234207,54.680065 -1.234175,54.680201 -1.234204,54.680465 -1.234300,54.681119 -1.234362,54.681549 -1.234427,54.681771 -1.234560,54.682172 -1.234782,54.682824 -1.236530,54.682837 -1.236725,54.682829 -1.237133,54.682813 -1.238813,54.683143 -1.241021,54.683814 -1.241819,54.683771 -1.242854,54.683717 -1.242946,54.683718 -1.243082,54.683716 -1.244694,54.683772 -1.244658,54.683077 -1.245038,54.682805 -1.245047,54.681990 -1.245011,54.681238 -1.245220,54.680975 -1.247056,54.680601 -1.248019,54.680404 -1.249478,54.680691"
    ), grammesCO2saved = c(2359, 2406), calories = c(211, 201
    ), type = c("route", "route")), .Names = c("rid", "start_id", 
"start_code", "end_id", "end_code", "strategy", "distance", "time_seconds", 
"calories", "document.id", "array.index", "start", "finish", 
"startBearing", "startSpeed", "start_longitude", "start_latitude", 
"finish_longitude", "finish_latitude", "crow_fly_distance", "event", 
"whence", "speed", "itinerary", "clientRouteId", "plan", "note", 
"length", "time", "busynance", "quietness", "signalledJunctions", 
"signalledCrossings", "west", "south", "east", "north", "name", 
"walk", "leaving", "arriving", "coordinates", "grammesCO2saved", 
"calories", "type"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: what would the expected output for your example be?

Comment: Use strsplit(df$coord, " ") will give you the three separate coordinates as a list.

Comment: @user1945827 I can't use strsplit because the number of coordinates varies between each row, and there are around a hundred coordinates per line

Comment: That just means that you'll need to find the longest of your split strings and fill in your shorter vectors with NA values.  You then need to bind the strings to your data.frame.  dput some of your data ...

Comment: @Zheyuan Li updated to show you the dput

Comment: mmmm ... your data has two rows of 45 columns.  The coordinates column splits to a list of two items one has 284 coordinates, the other has 322 coordinates.  I don't understand what you want to do with those coordinates.  We can tell you how to extract all of them out of the data.frame but we don't know where you want to put them afterwards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to end up with is a column in your data frame that for each row is a list (or data frame) with `x.coord` and `y.coord` columns. To achieve that, we can use `unnest` and `nest` from `tidyr` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- finalsub %>% mutate(coordinates = strsplit(coordinates,split=" ",fixed=TRUE)) %>%
                       unnest(coordinates) %>%
                       mutate(coordinates = strsplit(coordinates,split=",",fixed=TRUE),
                              x.coord = as.numeric(unlist(coordinates)[c(TRUE,FALSE)]),
                              y.coord = as.numeric(unlist(coordinates)[c(FALSE,TRUE)])) %>%
                       select(-coordinates) %>%
                       nest(x.coord,y.coord,.key=coordinates)
```

Notes:

1. The first `mutate` splits the character vector in your `coordinates` column by `" "` to separate each coordinate `x,y` resulting in a `list` of these.
2. `unnest` separates this list into rows.
3. In the second `mutate`, we first split each coordinate `x,y`, this time by `","` to separate each coordinate into `x` and `y`. Then we create separate `x.coord` and `y.coord` columns to hold these. Note the conversion to numeric here.
4. Finally, we use `nest` to collect the `x.coord` and `y.coord` columns as a list under the column named `coordinates`. Note that we first have to remove the original `coordinates` column.

The result using your `dput` data, printing only the `coordinates` column:

```
print(result$coordinates)
##[[1]]
### A tibble: 284 x 2
##     x.coord  y.coord
##       <dbl>    <dbl>
##1  -1.294832 54.61024
##2  -1.294883 54.61008
##3  -1.294262 54.61002
##4  -1.294141 54.61001
##5  -1.293710 54.61004
##6  -1.293726 54.61014
##7  -1.293742 54.61025
##8  -1.293510 54.61026
##9  -1.293368 54.61026
##10 -1.292816 54.61019
### ... with 274 more rows
##
##[[2]]
### A tibble: 322 x 2
##     x.coord  y.coord
##       <dbl>    <dbl>
##1  -1.294832 54.61024
##2  -1.294883 54.61008
##3  -1.294262 54.61002
##4  -1.294141 54.61001
##5  -1.293710 54.61004
##6  -1.293726 54.61014
##7  -1.293742 54.61025
##8  -1.293510 54.61026
##9  -1.293368 54.61026
##10 -1.292816 54.61019
### ... with 312 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(id= c(1,2), dist =c(45,23), speed = c(6,24) ,do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$cord,split = " ")))

library(reshape2)

df1 <- melt(df1,id=c("id","dist","speed"))

df2<- data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(df1$value, split=",")))
df1$value <- NULL
df1 <- cbind(df1,df2)
names(df1)[5:6] <- c("x","y")
id dist speed variable         x           y
1  1   45     6       X1  1.294832   54.610240
2  2   23    24       X1  2.788732   34.787940
3  1   45     6       X2 -1.294883   54.610080
4  2   23    24       X2  6.294883   24.567080
5  1   45     6       X3 -1.294262  54.6482757
6  2   23    24       X3 -5.564262 -45.7676757
```

Comment: @falcs Mostly this may helpful for you