# Convert a list in a dataframe to a lines

Tags: r, dataframe, lines, spatial-data-frame

I have a dataframe (`test`) in R. Inside one of the columns contains coordinates in this list structure:

```
> dput(test$coordinates)
list(structure(list(x = c(-1.294832, -1.294883, -1.294262, 
-1.249478), y = c(54.61024, 54.61008, 54.610016, 54.610006
)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -284L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I've reduced the number of coordinates for clarity.

Ultimately I wish to convert the dataframe into a spaitial lines dataframe but to do that I need the `test$coordinates` in a lines form. However, I get the following error

```
> lines(test$coordinates)
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

I have tried to convert the `test$coordinates` to other forms but it usually results in some error. How do I transform this list into a line?

Extra info this is a follow up question to

[Convert data frame to spatial lines data frame in R with x,y x,y coordintates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746698/convert-data-frame-to-spatial-lines-data-frame-in-r-with-x-y-x-y-coordintates/39749179#39749179)

UPDATE as requested `dput(head(test))`:

```
> dput(head(test))
structure(list(rid = 1, start_id = 1L, start_code = "E02002536", 
    end_id = 106L, end_code = "E02006909", strategy = "fastest", 
    distance = 12655L, time_seconds = 2921L, calories = 211L, 
    document.id = 1L, array.index = 1L, start = "Geranium Close", 
    finish = "Hylton Road", startBearing = 0, startSpeed = 0, 
    start_longitude = -1.294832, start_latitude = 54.610241, 
    finish_longitude = -1.249478, finish_latitude = 54.680691, 
    crow_fly_distance = 8362, event = "depart", whence = 1473171787, 
    speed = 20, itinerary = 419956, clientRouteId = 0, plan = "fastest", 
    note = "", length = 12655, time = 2921, busynance = 42172, 
    quietness = 30, signalledJunctions = 3, signalledCrossings = 2, 
    west = -1.300074, south = 54.610006, east = -1.232447, north = 54.683814, 
    name = "Geranium Close to Hylton Road", walk = 0, leaving = "2016-09-06 15:23:07", 
    arriving = "2016-09-06 16:11:48", grammesCO2saved = 2359, 
    calories2 = 211, type = "route", coordinates = list(structure(list(
        x = c(-1.294832, -1.294883, -1.294262, -1.294141, -1.29371, 
        -1.293726, -1.293742, -1.29351, -1.293368, -1.292816, 
        -1.248019, -1.249478), y = c(54.61024, 54.61008, 54.610016, 
        54.610006, 54.610038, 54.610142, 54.610247, 54.610262, 
        54.681238, 54.680975, 54.680601, 54.680404
        )), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -284L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")))), .Names = c("rid", "start_id", "start_code", 
"end_id", "end_code", "strategy", "distance", "time_seconds", 
"calories", "document.id", "array.index", "start", "finish", 
"startBearing", "startSpeed", "start_longitude", "start_latitude", 
"finish_longitude", "finish_latitude", "crow_fly_distance", "event", 
"whence", "speed", "itinerary", "clientRouteId", "plan", "note", 
"length", "time", "busynance", "quietness", "signalledJunctions", 
"signalledCrossings", "west", "south", "east", "north", "name", 
"walk", "leaving", "arriving", "grammesCO2saved", "calories2", 
"type", "coordinates"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Maybe better to include the output of `dput(head(test))`. Having said that, maybe `unnest` from the `tidyr` package can be of help.

Comment: @zheyuan Li, no. This question aims at creating spatial lines.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I've added the dput to the question

Comment: Structure of `$coordinates` is very weird. I get a bunch of NAs. Is this by design? Can you please `dput(test$coordinates)`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have it is the second line of the question, I agree the design is weird, that I why I want to change it to something better

Comment: Just give a reproducible example, unless NAs are there by design. The second update has NAs as well...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've updated the example so that the number of x coordinates equals the number of y coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines` is a plotting function. I'm assuming you want `sp::SpatialLines`. See `?"SpatialLines-class"` for how to construct such an object.

Here's for your case, provided you don't have a "corrupt" data.frame (see at the bottom of this post).

```
library(sp)
coords <- as.data.frame(xy$coordinates[[1]])[1:12, ]

out <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(coords)), ID = 1)))

An object of class "SpatialLines"
Slot "lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Lines"
Slot "Lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Line"
Slot "coords":
           x        y
1  -1.294832 54.61024
2  -1.294883 54.61008
3  -1.294262 54.61002
4  -1.294141 54.61001
5  -1.293710 54.61004
6  -1.293726 54.61014
7  -1.293742 54.61025
8  -1.293510 54.61026
9  -1.293368 54.68124
10 -1.292816 54.68097
11 -1.248019 54.68060
12 -1.249478 54.68040



Slot "ID":
[1] "1"



Slot "bbox":
        min       max
x -1.294883 -1.248019
y 54.610006 54.681238

Slot "proj4string":
CRS arguments: NA
```

To add data to this object, you should use

```
SpatialLinesDataFrame(out, data = yourdata)
```

but see [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163286/how-do-i-create-a-spatiallinesdataframe-from-a-dataframe) for more info.

There's a warning when I tried to coerce your coordinates to a data.frame. Hopefully this isnt' the case for your dataset.

```
> as.data.frame(xy$coordinates[[1]])
            x        y
1   -1.294832 54.61024
2   -1.294883 54.61008
3   -1.294262 54.61002
...
281      <NA>     <NA>
282      <NA>     <NA>
283      <NA>     <NA>
284      <NA>     <NA>

Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```